# Using a single LSTM model to forecast 350 micro segments?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am working on a project where I have to forecast sales of 350 micro-segments. I have data from 2015 at a monthly level for each of the micro-segment. The micro-segments are part of 11 segments and each of the segments has different trends. I tried to build a single LSTM model to forecast sales of all 350 micro-segments but it is not performing well.

I am going back 24 months and forecasting for the next 12 months, for each micro-segment I have 54 data points, and using the sliding window I get 18 data points for each micro-segment in train data.

I have the following questions(posting it in the same question as they are related):

1. Is building a single LSTM model for 350 segments with 54 data points of each segment a good option? or a separate model for 11 segments will make more sense.
2. How can I validate my model across different time steps with limited data?
3. Should I add a dummy variable to identify micro-segments?